# How to make a cat aware that you fear them and to have them in a calm state when near me?

Tags: cats

I know the question sound stupid and you wonder why we got a kitten if im scared but i really do love her and find her adorable its just i had this fear of animals that every time i see them im scared to be attacked or hurt by them and really i love my cat but whenever she shows any type of playfulness i assume its aggression and get scared and back away there are sometimes where she is calm and sleeps on me which i like its just i feel scared whenever she acts playful since my mind assumes that she is getting aggressive so id be thankful if someone could give me some tips to help me with this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about pets, it's about a personal problem that should be addressed accordingly.

Comment: There is no "magic wand" that will make a *kitten* "calm when near someone who's scared of it." You'll need to address your own fears, likely with professional help. That you already find the kitten adorable and feel affection toward her is very promising, but strangers on the internet can't help you resolve your own issues. For the benefit of both of you, please find someone who can offer the help you need.

Comment: Actually there *is* an answer to this question - “you can’t, you need to tackle the issue from another angle” is a valid answer in my opinion.

Comment: you handle this in the same way as you do when meeting any new person you learn about eachother.